# NextJS Error: Not implemented when using cache

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

Using next@13.4.1 version with `app` directory and react@18.2.0

In my application, I want to use the cache to build my user menu. So, I created a utility like that:

```js
import { cache } from 'react';

export const getUserMenu = cache(async () => {
  const headers = {};
  const params = { headers, method: 'GET', next: { revalidate: 60 } };
  const menusReq = await fetch('/api/Menu', { ...params });

  if (menusReq.status === 200) {
    const json = await menusReq.json();

    return json.data ?? [];
  }

  return [];
});
```

And I call it in my layout like that:

```js
'use client';

import type { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { use } from 'react';

import Nav from '@/lib/components/Nav';
import { getUserMenu } from '@/utils/getUserMenu';

type IAdminLayoutProps = {
  children?: ReactNode;
};

async function fetchMenu() {
  const res = await getUserMenu();
  return res;
}

const dataPromise = fetchMenu();

export default function AdminLayout({ children }: IAdminLayoutProps) {

  const items = use(dataPromise);

  return (
    <main>
      <Nav items={items} />
      {children}
    </main>
  );
}
```

But when I go on the page, I see my menu and my items fetched in the API, but I have this error in my console :
[my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHd2A.jpg)

Wanted to build my menu with the react cache

Comment: @currenthandle Not for the moment

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when I used cache under 'use client'

Try moving the client items to a new component and let the page as a server component calling whatever the function using cache... Pass the properties to the client or try hydrate it.

I am currently using my page with @tanstack/react-query like this, after replacing all 'use client' components.

My query client:

```
import { QueryClient } from '@tanstack/query-core'
import { cache } from 'react'

export const getQueryClient = cache(() => new QueryClient())
```

Page.tsx

```
import { dehydrate } from '@tanstack/react-query'

import { Hydrate } from '../lib/hydrate'
import { type Species } from '../types/species'
import { client } from '../lib/gql-client'
import { getQueryClient } from '../lib/query-client'

import { GetSpeciesDocument, useGetSpeciesQuery } from '../lib/graphql'
import SpeciesPage from './_components/hydratedPage'

type SpeciesProps = {
  params: {
    locale: string
  }
}

const Species = async ({ params: { locale } }: SpeciesProps) => {
  const queryClient = getQueryClient()
  await queryClient.prefetchQuery({
    queryKey: useGetSpeciesQuery.getKey({ locale }),
    queryFn: () => client.request<Species>(GetSpeciesDocument, { locale }),
  })
  const dehydratedState = dehydrate(queryClient)

  return (
    <Hydrate state={dehydratedState}>
      <SpeciesPage params={{ locale }} />
    </Hydrate>
  )
}

export default Species
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Next or React could be out of date (try removing `.next` and `node_modules` folder to re-install). It works fine with react 18.2.0 and next 13.4.2

But I got this error when I tried to use React in an environment that didn't have support for server side cache (namely Astro).

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue when trying to implement tanstack react-query with SSR in accordance with their docs. I have "react": "18.2.0" & "next": "13.4.7" I rm'd my .next and node_modules and reinstalled but it didn't do anything...

Comment: same on my end
"react": "^18.2.0",
"next": "13.4.10-canary.0",

Comment: That makes one more of us. I can't upgrade to newer nextjs versions since AWS Amplify is having an issue. Good to know that it's not because of my current version.

Comment: The problem comes if u use cache function from react, u can use memoize from lodash as alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, [`React.cache()` is only for use in server components](https://react.dev/reference/react/cache), and in the original question `cache()` is inside of a [client component](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components), denoted by the `"use client"` directive at the top of the file.

It's important to note that this may still be the case even if you don't see `"use client"` at the top of the file due to how [`"use client"` marks a boundary for client side rendering](https://react.dev/reference/react/use-client#how-use-client-marks-client-code), causing all imported child components and utility functions, like `getUserMenu` in the question, to also render on the client.

To fix this error, you have a few options:

**Option 1: Make the component that uses `cache()` a server component**

This option can be the easiest if you didn't intend the current component to render on the client side.

1. Remove `"use client"` from the top of the file
2. Remove `"use client"` from the top of any file that imports the component
3. Test to see if your application still works

If your application works and you no longer see the not implemented error, perfect!

If it doesn't work anymore, you likely are using a React API that requires running on the client on one of those components. You can either refactor the component to not use client APIs — in the original question this would be replacing `use(dataPromise)` with `await dataPromise` — or you may want to try one of the other options.

**Option 2: Pass the result of the cache from a server component into the client component**

This option is great for running the cache call on the server while still using client-side APIs like event handlers and many hooks.

1. Remove the call to cache from the client component. In the case of the original example, that would mean to remove the import of `getUserMenu`
2. Use cache in the file of the closest parent server component
3. Pass the result into the client component as a prop
4. If your cache includes an asynchronous function, you may either await the result before passing it as a prop (below), or [stream the promise with `Suspense` and `use()`](https://react.dev/reference/react/use#streaming-data-from-server-to-client)

**`ExampleServerComponent.tsx`**

```
import { cache } from "react";
import { ExampleClientComponent } from "./ExampleClientComponent";

const getCachedValue = cache(async () => {
  return await "This is the cached value from the server. It was in a promise, just like fetch() calls.";
});

const value = getCachedValue();

export const ExampleServerComponent = async () => {
  return <ExampleClientComponent cachedValueFromServer={await value} />;
};
```

[See more code and run the simplified example on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/next-js-client-cache-7vtvgm?file=%2Fcomponents%2FExampleServerComponent.tsx%3A2%2C65)

**Option 3: Use a client-side caching like `useMemo()` instead of `cache()`**

This option depends a lot on the specific constraints of your implementation. If you intended for the cached function to run on the client, data fetching using `useEffect()` or `useMemo()` may be desired over `React.cache()` on the server.

---

**A note on React Versions in Next.js**

At the time of writing, Next.js [precompiles React canary](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/292ebad893217b57d79aae33715b877a054931ab/packages/next/src/compiled/react) into their prod and dev servers, overriding any version of React you have installed. So even if you see `react@v18.2.0` while running `npm ls react`, you will likely see a different version by performing a `console.log(React.version)` inside a React component.

If you're worried that you have the wrong version of React in your Next.js project, try the `console.log(React.version)` check. Updating Next.js will update the included precompiled React version.

[Learn more about React canary version pinning](https://react.dev/blog/2023/05/03/react-canaries)